# SSL ownership information

Tags: ssl

I just installed my SSL certificate and I noticed something. When I open https://paypal.com in chrome it appears information about the certificate in the search bar.

[image: Paypal certificate information]

But when I open this website https://www.myvessyl.com/, the SSL certificate is installed and configured too but is not showing the information as Paypal.com. What's happening?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more money you can buy an ["Extended Validation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate) SSL certificate, which causes the browsers to display the green bar.  The certificate authority works harder to verify your identity when you do this.